# Gauss algorithm for mxn matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

The code below works until a certain point, but some lines of the matrix should appear in a different form. The functions that are lacking work, and just change and sum two lines.
The matrix I'm working with only has 0's and 1's.

```
int Gauss_elimination(int **matrix, int lines, int columns){

    int i, j=0, k, pivot=0;
    while(j<columns && pivot<lines){
        i=pivot;
        while((i<lines) && (matrix[i][j]==0)){
            i++;
        }
        if(i<lines){         
            if(i>pivot){
                Swap_lines(matrix, columns, i, pivot);
            }
            k=pivot+1;
            while(k<lines){
                if(matrix[k][j]==1){          
                    Sum_lines(matrix, columns, pivot, k);
                }
                k++;
            }
            pivot++;
        }
        j++;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Note that 2D arrays and double pointers are *not* interchangable

Comment: The function swap was also written by me, I just ommited the code here.

Comment: 1.you should add comments to the source, 2.you should sort lines before GEM to avoid getting stuck (beware linear combinations lines and zeros). GEM is not 100% safe when programmed without safety checks, determinant based inverse is simpler and safe.